# What is the Big O for `append` in golang?

Tags: go

What is the Big O for

```
    a := []int32{1,2,3,4,5}
    a = append(a,6)

    fmt.Println(a)
```

Is it O(1) or O(n) if I'm just appending 1 item?
and also for

```
    a := []int32{1,2,3,4,5}
    b := []int32{6,7,8}
    a = append(a,b...)
    
    fmt.Println(a)
```

Comment: The amortized cost of append is O(1). Worst case it is O(n). append grows the slice by doubling its capacity.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: based on the [source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go), it seems to double up to 1024, then add 25%. (However this is still O(n) worst case and O(1) amortized, as you say)

Answer (score -3):

BigO depends on the algorithm used and not the programming language
Also, BigO is talked about when the input size is sufficiently large (Refer definition of BigO)
So BigO for one element doesn't exist.

Appending in go seems to be a bit complicated, so to get at the  time complexity by yourself, have a look at this

https://hackernoon.com/golang-slice-and-append-e18498cf924a